# Implementing column generation technique in linear programming with the use of JOptimizer java library?

Tags: java, linear-programming, joptimizer

To tell the truth you require some advance Math knowledge and java fluency to understand what I am asking for!
Column generation is an technique for optimizing some task related to patterns finding.
In programming, we are addicted to solve some problems by finding all the possible occurrences and choose the best solution from it.
But it is much time consuming thing.
When dealing with a large number of data set the time required will be 2-3 day unless we don't have a super computer.
But, I do some research on it and found something called COLUMN GENERATION in linear programming.
If there are someone who implemented it in java please guide me!
(Usually I use [JOptimizer](http://www.joptimizer.com/) to develop my linear programming related apps)

Sorry if this is a strange question, and thank you to everyone who takes the time to consider it.

Comment: Have you checked weka?

Comment: Not yet. Are you?

Comment: I have found some implementation of column generation technique with the use of IBM's CPLEX library.

Comment: [CutStock.java](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B84k1fZRHSMdLWwtYXd5N0xKRjQ/view?usp=sharing) implements the column generation technique to solve stock cutting problem. The code is bit longer to put on stack overflow.

Comment: I realized that CPLEX is a Native API. It causes the java's portability. So, I need to find a way to implement it with some 100% java library like JOptimizer. But I didn't find one yet. If someone know some library or method, please let me know.